# I am trying to execute pg_basebackup command to take base backup but I do not see a success statement when I execute the command

Tags: postgresql, shell

```
pg_basebackup -U xxxxx -h xxxxx -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/backups/ `date +%Y%m%d` -X stream -P -v -Ft -z
```

and it is showing error as

> pg_basebackup: too many command-line arguments (first is "20180319")

Comment: what is this date doing in the command?

Comment: It is showing error like that..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the date to be part of the path:

```
-D "/var/lib/pgsql/10/backups/`date +%Y%m%d`"
```

Comment: Tq. But I got another error saying    pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "local host", user "postgres", SSL off

Comment: You probably have no `replication` entry in `pg_hba.conf` (or you did not reload).